Why is there a NullPointerException for getApplicationContext() when context is not null?
What exactly is the null object reference on which getApplicationContext() is being invoked, in this error message:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
at
android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:150)

Because I have now introduced the following debugging code:
fun getDatabase(context: Context, scope: CoroutineScope): MyRoomDatabase {
        if (context != null) {
            val test = context.applicationContext
        } else {
            throw Exception("Why is it NULL?")
        }

And the exception thrown is not "Why is it NULL?". The debugger reaches the line val test = ..., indicating that "context" is non-null, before throwing the NullPointerException anyway. So where should I be looking for the source of this error?

From the stack trace, the context argument is apparently a ContextWrapper, which is a Context that wraps another Context. That NPE means that the inner wrapped Context is null.

…or another one that's wrapped further in is null, I should say. There's no limit on the number of wrappers. It's often the first one in, though, since this usually happens when a component Context – e.g., an Activity or Service – is being used too early, or when you've instantiated a Context directly somehow.

Look at the caller of this method. It is probably passing a Context parameter that has not been properly initialized. This usually happens when you instantiate an Android component (like Activity or Service manually, instead of letting Android instantiate it for you.

To save yourself a lot of debugging time in the future, pay attention to the detail of error messsages and stack traces. If it was the parameter context that was null, the stack trace would have shown the NPE being thrown in your own code. But as you can see, it wasn't; it was thrown in ContextWrapper.java. Making use of that information would have saved you a lot of time.

And, in the future, please post the entire stack trace, not just one line.
